# Routine that causes delay in assembly using 1ah

Tags: assembly, x86, delay, nasm

I am having trouble undersating this routine that causes a delay using `int 1ah`. I am aware that `int 1ah` is related to the *system clock*, but I don't understand how that is being used in this function.

```
delay:
pusha
pushf

mov ah, 0
int 1ah
mov di, 30
mov ah, 0
int 1ah
mov bx, dx

wait:
mov ah, 0
int 1ah
sub dx, bx
cmp di, dx
ja wait
popf
popa
ret
```

Why is the register `di` being used here? Can I use another jump instruction instead of `ja`? How is the delay time calculated?

Comment: Did you read [the manual](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2271.htm)?

Comment: @fuz I read about int 1ah, but in everything I found, int 1ah came with another parameter, like int 1ah, 00h. In this routine there is no other parameter.

Comment: Is ah the parameter by default?

Comment: @emic - yes, ah is the parameter.

Comment: @emic The BIOS uses whatever is currently in `ah` to determine what function it should execute. If you look at the code, it carefully sets `ah` to zero before executing interrupt `1ah`.

Comment: @fuz mov ah, 0 and int 1ah are used to get the system time, correct? What about the di register? Why is it used in this case?

Comment: _DI_ is set to 30 before the loop and isn't destroyed by calls to _int 1ah/ah=0_ . That is why _DI_ was chosen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
delay:
pusha
pushf
```

Preserves all current register values into stack.

```
mov ah, 0
int 1ah
```

Calls the BIOS service "1Ah, 00" (returns `cx:dx` = number of ticks since midnight, `al` = midnight flag since last call). Results of this call are not used for anything.

```
mov di, 30
```

`di = 30` (will be used to somewhat delay the execution sometimes).

```
mov ah, 0
int 1ah
```

Call "1Ah, 00" again, refreshing `cx:dx` + `al` results.

```
mov bx, dx
```

Copy current ticks counter low 16b into `bx`.

```
wait:
mov ah, 0
int 1ah
```

Call "1Ah, 00" again, refreshing `cx:dx` + `al` results.

```
sub dx, bx
```

Subtract from fresh low 16b ticks the value stored ahead of loop.

```
cmp di, dx
```

Compare 30 with the result of subtraction.

```
ja wait
```

If the result was from 0 to 29, it will jump to `wait`, for 30 to 65535 it will continue with return sequence. This works well even for situations when `bx = 65530` for example, and the low 16b of counter did reset through 0, the delta calculated by `sub` will still grow steadily from 0 to 30.

```
popf
popa
ret
```

Restores everything and returns.

---

So this procedure will wait roughly 30 ticks (~1.65s if the default DOS timer speed is used).

The only time when this may wait unexpected amount of ticks is around midnight, when the returned `dx` will suddenly jump to 0 value, and in most of the cases that will trigger end of delay loop, so at midnight the delay may be shortened artificially.